Issue with Indexing New Domain After Moving Website
I recently moved my WordPress website to a new domain with the same content as the old site. Unfortunately, I made an error during the migration process. I removed the old content and deleted the old property from Google Search Console without notifying Google about the domain change.
To rectify this, I created a new Google Search Console account for the new domain and submitted the sitemaps. Additionally, I manually submitted individual pages using the URL Inspection tool and set the canonical links on every page (leading to the new website) using the Yoast SEO plugin. However, it has been over a week, and my new website still isn't indexed.
Can someone advise on how to resolve this indexing issue? Any guidance on the correct steps to ensure my new domain is properly indexed would be greatly appreciated.

Typically it takes several weeks (sometimes a couple of months) for Google to actually index new content.  Even though your content is the same as your old site, to Google it's a new domain with new content.
